# Pass char[N] param to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

i have a variable declared as

```
char myvariable[N] = "blablabla"
```

and i need to pass it to a thread

```
DWORD MyThread(LPVOID lpdwParam)
```

i tried to cast inside the thread function the lpdwParam in char* but it doesn't work. How can i fix it?

**EDIT 1**

Here the complete part of code

```
char myvariable[16];

GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, IDC_IPADDRESS, &myvariable[0], 16);

myThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyThread, (LPVOID)&myvariable, 0, &myThreadId);

DWORD MyThread(LPVOID lpdwParam)
{
    char *myvariable2 = (char *)lpdwParam;

    ....
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Doesn't work means that myvariable2 doesn't contains the text of myvariable

**EDIT 3**

```
char *myvariable = new char[16];

GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg, IDC_IPADDRESS, myvariable, 16);

myThreadHandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MyThread, (LPVOID)myvariable, 0, &myThreadId);
```

and the thread function:

```
char *myvariable2 = (char *)lpdwParam;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing something like this:

```
// ...
char myvariable[N] = "blablabla";
HANDLE hThread=CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThread, (LPVOID)myvariable, 0); // however you should use beginthread to avoid troubles with the CRT
// ...


DWORD MyThread(LPVOID lpdwParam)
{
    char * mystring = (char *)lpdwParam;
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

and you don't get the correct characters by reading `mystring`, my guess is that, being `myvariable` allocated on the stack, it goes out of scope before `MyThread` gets the chance to run, thus you get the same kind of problems you encounter when you return a pointer to a local variable.

The solution would be to allocate dynamically your string:

```
// ...
char * myvariable = new char[N];
*myvariable=0;
strncat(myvariable, "blablabla", N); // this is equivalent to what the nonstandard strlcpy would do
HANDLE hThread=CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThread, (LPVOID)myvariable, 0); // however you should use beginthread to avoid troubles with the CRT
// ...


DWORD MyThread(LPVOID lpdwParam)
{
    char * mystring = (char *)lpdwParam;
    // ...
    // when you're done with mystring, remember to free it; even better, use a smart pointer
    delete [] mystring;
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

By the way, notice that, as already said in the snippets, if you plan to use CRT functions inside your newly created thread you shouldn't use `CreateThread` directly, but you should instead use the `_beginthread`/`_beginthreadex` functions, because otherwise some CRT per-thread structures may not get initialized correctly.

---

#### Addendum

> i edited my code to use new char[16] but it doesn't work. When i cast the variable from LPVOID to char* inside the thread function i get only strange symbols

If you changed the code so that myvariable is now a pointer, you should remove the `&` from the call to `CreateThread`; `&` was superfluous when it was used with the array (in that case just using its name was enough), but now that `myvariable` is a pointer it is plain wrong, since using it on `myvariable` will provide the address of `myvariable` instead of the address stored in `myvariable`.

Long story short, remove that ampersand.

Comment: I believe that this isn't the case any longer.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9ha0zh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx "_beginthread and _beginthreadex are similar to the CreateThread function in the Win32 API but has these differences: - They initialize certain C run-time library variables. This is important only if you use the C run-time library in your threads." That documentation refers to VS2010, so I suppose it still applies.

Comment: @Stefano: your edits confirms my guess. Try to follow the advice given in my answer.

Comment: i edited my code to use new char[16] but it doesn't work. When i cast the variable from LPVOID to char* inside the thread function i get only strange symbols

Comment: @Stefano: see addendum in the answer.

Comment: @Stefano: could you post the code you're trying at the moment?

Comment: @Stefano: hmm, I don't know, now it should work... did you try to perform a full rebuild of your project, just for safety? :S

Comment: i solved, i forgot to remove after the CreateThread call the delete [] myvariable

Comment: @Stefano: Great; just remember to free that memory inside the thread when you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If your doing c++ casting, you will need to use `const char* var = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(lpdwParam);`. Just be careful though, if its a stack string, it'll probably pass out of scope before the thread uses it, if its a static string, you should use `const` to preventing any accidental overwriting of data